# TicTacToe in Java - why does it go on too long?

Tags: java

I am writing a TicTacToe game, and it repeatedly prompts the user for a move. It is asking for a selection more than 9 times and I am not sure why.

My design has a 2-dimensional array to store information about the current state of the board, use JOptionPane to ask users for selection of the board (1 for top left, 2 for top middle, 3 for top right, 4 for middle left, etc). After every move, output into the console the current board. If a spot is already used, prompt the user again. (There is no need for a winner check, as we were told to do this another time.

Here is my entire code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

// Basic TicTacToe game.
public class TicTacToe1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Hello there!
        Object[] options = { "I'm ready to play!",};
        Object[] options2 = { "Select another number.",};
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"To play TicTacToe, use the numbers 1 to 9 to choose where you place a mark. Are you ready?","TicTacToe1",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        // Define the board.
        char board[][] = new char[3][3];
        // Zero out the board.
        for(int a=0; a<3; a++) {
            for(int b=0; b<3; b++) {
                board[a][b] = ' ';
            }
        }
        // Print an initial, clean board.
        print(board);
        // Use a for loop to ask for the selection and nest the selector into it.
        for(int i=1; i<10 ; i++) {
            if ((i%2) == 1) {
                boolean goahead = true;
                while (goahead) {
                    int selection = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Where do you want to place an X?"));
                    if ((board[(((selection-1)-((selection-1)%3))/3)][(selection-1)%3]=='X') || (board[(((selection-1)-((selection-1)%3))/3)][(selection-1)%3]=='O')) {
                        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"I'm sorry, the number "+selection+" spot is already being used.","TicTacToe1",
                                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options2, options2[0]);
                    } else {
                        goahead = false;
                        board[(((selection-1)-((selection-1)%3))/3)][(selection-1)%3] = 'X';
                        print(board);
                    }
                }
            }
            if ((i%2) == 1) {
                boolean goahead = true;
                while (goahead) {
                    int selection = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Where do you want to place an O?"));
                    if ((board[(((selection-1)-((selection-1)%3))/3)][(selection-1)%3]=='X') || (board[(((selection-1)-((selection-1)%3))/3)][(selection-1)%3]=='O')) {
                        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"I'm sorry, the number "+selection+" spot is already being used.","TicTacToe1",
                                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options2, options2[0]);
                    } else {
                        goahead = false;
                        board[(((selection-1)-((selection-1)%3))/3)][(selection-1)%3] = 'O';
                        print(board);
                    }
                }
            }
//          didsomeonewinyet(board);
        }
    }

    // Make a helper function named print to print the board
    public static void print(char board[][]){
        for(int a=0; a<3; a++) {
            for(int b=0; b<3; b++) {
                System.out.print("|"+board[a][b]+"|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // Winner checker.
//  public static void didsomeonewinyet(char board[][]){
        // Manually checking will yield 16 cases (2 diagonal, 3 horizontal, 3 vertical, either X or O), which is not that bad.
//  }
}
```

Why does it ask for a selection too many times?

Comment: We won't debug the code for you. Use a debugger to walk through your code and see why it loops more than 9 times. If you still have problems, you can tell us the problem and then we will help.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone on here, but I for one don't like helping people with homework. You have a teacher, ask them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, "chattiness" is strongly discouraged, especially at the beginning of a question, since the first few sentences of a question are shown on the various lists of questions, and because people scan quickly to see if there's something they happen to know the answer to. Your entire first three paragraphs are the sort of thing we discourage. Your question should basically open with "I'm writing a Tic-Tac-Toe game..." and pick up with your fourth paragraph. Please take this constructively, that's how it's meant. :-) Welcome again!

Comment: Quick hint: your input dialog is inside your `for` loop.

Comment: at a quick glance in your for loop you have 2 if conditions that are checking the same thing

Comment: I'll second @T.J.Crowder's comment, and suggest you do the following: (1) delete this question; (2) use a debugger to step through your code a line at a time (3) If you still can't figure it out, post a new question without the chattiness, explaining _exactly_ where you see something in the debugger that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also please don't let the downvotes on the question bother you. A lot of people's first questions get downvoted. (In this case, in my humble opinion, inappropriately.) That's just part of learning how the place works. It won't take you long at all.

Comment: Sorry, me again. :-) Last bit of advice: When you post a question, hang around for the first five minutes or so, because that's when people are most likely to ask you to clarify or improve it, and doing so right away makes it **dramatically** more likely you'll get a good answer. This isn't like old bulletin boards. You post a question, and people are likely to be *all over it* within seconds. Best,

Comment: @JimGarrison please DO NOT suggest to new users that they delete bad questions. That can lead to a question ban. They should IMPROVE the questions that they have asked. It would be great if the asker gained some insight with the debugger, but deleting bad questions is a poor SO strategy for a newcomer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I completely understand. I am using eclipse right now to code in - how would I go about debugging my code in it?

Comment: @EugeneLee Again, that is a lot to say in a small comment here. Google it and then try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if conditions in the for loop are the same so they both occur during the same iteration of the loop:

```
if ((i%2) == 1) {
```

one of the if statements should be:

```
if ((i%2) == 0) {
```

depending on who you want to go first.

Alternatively you could just use an else statement:

```
if ((i%2) == 1) {
 //code for x to go

}else {
//code for y to go
}
```

Comment: Ah damnit I read over my code way too many times and din't catch that. Is there anything I can do to catch errors like that?

Comment: @EugeneLee Well I put a System.out.println(); statement at the top of the loop telling me when it was reaching the top. And the console was printing:top of loop twice in a row. SOPL statements are very good for when you come across an error.